# Android callscreen Intent/broadcast?

Tags: android

When a Call is received, is there a intent of broadcast received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

You need to implement onCallStateChanged(). State that you need to monitor is CALL_STATE_RINGING.

In order to use that you need to declare the READ_PHONE_STATE permission in your manifest.

UPDATE (after suggestion):

Broadcast ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED is described under

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: There is an equivalent broadcast as well, `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`, defined on `TelephonyManager`.

Comment: I guess it is easier to handle. And in fact it is closer to what exactly was asked for in this question.